# Add custom parameter to site URL whith saving on page changes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a project, third-party developers of a mobile application for the site were asked to do the following:
"You need to create a parameter for the URL: **?app=1** so that the site address looks like this:

https://site.name/?app=1

At the same time, it is important that all links that will be opened from this address must save the **?app=1** parameter."

Please tell me how can this be done? What to study or read on this topic?

Comment: localhost/myapp/index.php?app=1   ->  <?php var_dump($_REQUEST['app']);  ?>

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you are looking for [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).